# APEX 5 interactive report column order

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an issue with changing interactive report column order.
My APEX version 5.0.3.00.03.

If i change order in Columns nothing change.
If i change order in SqlQuery nothing change.
If i change type of report (eg select classic report) and come back to interactive order finally change.

I'm doing wrong or there is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL statement order is merely defines the default order upon creation, and has no impact afterwards.

Classic reports get their order from the column sequence at design time.

Column order for interactive reports is defined at runtime, where the developer uses action toolbar to select columns, order, sort etc.

Design time capability for IR may be present in APEX 5.2

Comment: Update - it's now 18.1, and we're still waiting on IR design time upgrades.

Comment: 19.1 and I still have to come to this question to find out how to design column order.

Comment: Still something we do at runtime, as a developer.

Answer (score 13):

So what we can do here is, once you run your report and see the output.

Click on "Action" button on your report output, near the Search bar. Then choose "columns". Now in the next pop up window, you can reorder the columns and even opt to not show some of the column. Once you are done with the changes, click on "Apply".

Now you need to follow these steps to make these changes default for all.
Actions --> Reports --> Save Report --> Choose "As Default Report Settings" in save drop down menu --> Apply.

Now your changes will be done and saved as default for all.

Answer (score 2):

To change the order of columns displayed go on IR bar "actions" and select "Columns". Here you can choose what display and in which order. Then save the report as default.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to save the report as default report afterwards or else it will reset on refresh (actions -> save report then choose default from select list).

Comment: While this might be a good tip, it's not an answer to the question asked - this could perhaps be a comment on the question.

Comment: Actions > Report > Save Report